# md-grid-list: re-ordering of items

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and have been looking at the md-grid-list lately for a design requirement I am trying to solve.

I have a bunch of div's that are children to a container with layout row applied. Each of the child items have set widths\heights and have a toggle button to expand\collapse, which just doubles their sizes on expand and then return to original sizes on collapse.

What I'd like is for the child items to re-order to fill available space (provided that space is big enough) around other items that have been expanded.

[image]

Right now the container element for my child items also has layout-wrap applied and so of course as items gets expanded, any children that don't fit horizontally just push down below the previous item.

I have come across md-grid-list but I am not so sure this will provide me with what I am after,  as it seems to be more suited for percentage based sizes - or have I got that wrong?

I have seen http://masonry.desandro.com/ where if you resize the window on the homepage, that's the kind of behaviour I am looking for, although I would not want the height\widths to update dynamically.

Can this behaviour be achieved using Angular Material components alone?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but that is exactly what the grid does?

You just set the column count and width/height ratio. You can also set the height of the rows in pixels. And you can configure it depending on CSS breakpoints.

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="4"
    md-row-height-gt-md="{{height ? '100px' : '1:1'}}" md-row-height="100px"
    md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">

    <md-grid-tile class="gray" md-rowspan="2" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#1: (2r x 2c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="green">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#2: (1r x 1c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>
```

As you can see I added a toggle to switch height between ratio and fixed heigth: `md-row-height-gt-md="{{height ? '100px' : '1:1'}}"`.
Everything is animated by default but you can roll your own animations with angular-animate.

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/QyxOQo

Comment: Thanks @kuhnroyal for your answer, but the more I look md-grid-list and how it works the less I think I can use it for my scenario. I want to be able to toggle the size of child items without causing other non expanded children to change size. With md-grid-list working off row and col-span values, it means I cant work with fixed dimensions on the child items.